# How can i make sure i am using latest version of inapp purchase in android?

Tags: android, authentication, in-app-purchase, google-play

I have implemented in-app Purchases in my application and that was working fine but now its not working and displaying an error of Authentication require, You need to sign in you google account. While i am already signed in, and have also applied almost all suggestions on this error including resetting my device. Now on some other apps my in-app purchase works fine but on that particular app its not working. Most possible reason is i might be using v2 in that build, but how can i make sure either i am using v2 or v3. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem it was because i am using an API to get inapp products details and in-app product id was updated but not updated on google playstore console, so when it don't find any in-app product with that id, it displays this error. It was a silly mistake but wasted my 4-5 hours to identify.